# Matching cell arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, match, cell-array

I am trying to find indices of the elements in one cell array in another cell array in MATLAB. For example:

```
a = {'Hello', 'Good', 'Sun', 'Moon'};
b = {'Well', 'I', 'You', 'Hello', 'Alone', 'Party', 'Long', 'Moon'};
```

I expect to get the following result which shows the index of elements of $a$ in array $b$:

```
index=[4, NaN, NaN, 8];
```

I know it is possible to implement it using loops, but I think there is simple way to do that which I don't know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ismember`

```
[flag,index] = ismember ( a, b )
```

Answer (score 3):

With [`ismember`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) -

```
[matches,index] = ismember(a,b)
index(~matches) = nan
```

---

With [`intersect`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) -

```
[~,pos,idx] = intersect(a,b)
index = nan(1,numel(a))
index(pos) = idx
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the 2nd output argument of ismember:

```
[ida,idb]=ismember(a, b)

ida =    1     0     0     1
idb=     4     0     0     8
```

If you really need NaN just do:

```
idb( idb == 0 ) = NaN
```